# Can't change navigation bar color to white

Tags: xcode, colors, navigation

I can make the navigation bar black or any other color but when I try white, it just makes it grey. For the curious, here's the code I'm using:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Just setting the translucency off did the trick.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

When I stop and think about it, it should have been obvious.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the colour of a individual bar put the following in your .m file:

Creating the navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
```

Changing the color of the bar:

```
myNavigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

`setBarTintColor` is a tint, meaning that it's tinted — which is why you see gray instead of white (if not overlaying white). If you want to fill the navigation bar with a solid color then try using `setBackGroundColor`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

If you still wanted some control with the alpha values you could use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

> Beginning with iOS 7, navigation bars, tab bars, and tool bars
>   (henceforth referred to as 'bars') are configured to be translucent by
>   default. A translucent bar mixes its barTintColor with gray before
>   combining it with a system-defined alpha value to produce the final
>   background color that is used to composite the bar with the content it
>   overlies.

↳ [UIColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithWhite:alpha:)

Comment: Seemed promising but it didn't work. Still grey. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3606650, Show the code you're using and an image of the screen perhaps.

Comment: I used the code you suggested (copy and paste). Used it in app delegate, even in the VC viewdidappear method. No Go. I even tried a white image and tried to set that as background image. Even that produces grey tint. Tried playing around with tint color and opacity. It just produces a grey tinted bar always.

Answer (score 0):

I made new class CustomViewController.swift, like this:

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let nav = self.navigationBar
        nav.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        nav.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        //nav.tintColor = UIColor.white
        nav.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        nav.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

It's not work till I remove in another class lines that overvrite my changes:

```
//nc.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
//nc.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bar_background"), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS13, the new way to customize navigation bar is to use UINavigationBarAppearance.

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
    // or navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Note:

- `.scrollEdgeAppearance` will be used if your view contains a
  scrollview and it’s scrolled at the top
- `.compactAppearance` for
  iPhone in landscape
- `.standardAppearance` for the rest